# Google Cloud Platform Dataset can't show image in VertexAI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Thanks All:
When I use GCP-VertexAI and upload image from my computer. Next step to Browse page, all images always are loading. I can't any picture in Browse, and labing. But we can find upload image in Cloud Storage. How should I do for check my images in Browse?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4gFz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps that you have mentioned and my images are loading properly.
I tried with multiple high resolution images with different pixels and dimensions and those successfully loaded.

Could you please follow  these troubleshooting steps to see if the images are pulled from the Cloud Storage bucket?

**Steps:**

1. Open Vertex AI in the Console, go to the dataset and then go to the browse section where you have your images still loading.
2. Open the developer tools option or inspect tools options in the browser.
3. Select Network and filter by images i.e (Img)
   [image]
4. Select one of your images and check the status of that image,  to see whether it is in stalled or waiting state.
   If it is in stalled or waiting state, already some images are there in the queue that are not yet pulled.
5. If the images are pulled successfully  from the bucket then you can see the **content Download** will show a blue mark as shown in the below snapshot.
   [image]